# Using multiple application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to have two application.properties files:
1. src/main/resources/application.properties
2. src/test/resources/application.properties
but I want that during test run it will use both files.
for instance: 
In src/main/resources/application.properties:

```
a=b
c=d
```

In src/test/resources/application.properties:

```
e=f
```

and during test run I will be able use all the properties I listed from both files.

```
@Value("${a}")
private String a;
@Value("${c}")
private String c;
@Value("${e}")
private String e;
```

Is it possible? 
If not - what is the best practice to do what I want?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need an additional variable "e" for tests? Ideally you should be using same set of variables in application and its tests.

Comment: A Spring boot app will look first in the application-xxx.properties associated to its current configuration (eg application-dev.properties for development), then default to the application.properties file if the property it's looking for isn't found. How about a application.properties which contains a=b, c=d, then in your application-test.properties set e=f ?

Comment: In my case its relevant because I want to set the pact broker details in application-test.properties (because tht's relevant only for pact tests). I need the other configurations which set in application.properties as well. Otherwise, it's not getting compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

I had to use src/test/resources/**application-test**.properties (and not src/test/resources/**application**.properties) and add the following annotation:

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
```